# plugin not working as I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, siblings

I was using the following code to cycle though a set of elements.

```
$(this).next().show().animate({top: '25px'},250,function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
```

but this was limited as I needed to get to the end of the list of elements, and cycle through again, so I wrote this plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        rotater: function(class_check){
            return this.each(function(){
                if($(this).next().hasClass(class_check)){

                    return $(this).next();
                } else {

                    return $(this).parent().children().first();
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In order to detect when I had reached the end of my desired set (which all share a common class) and if so, grab the first object in which to start the whole cycle again.

I changed the calling code to:

```
$(this).rotater('common_class').show().animate({top: '25px'},250,function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
```

but it has ceased to work entirely!! I am confused, I could understand if my "return to beginning" script failed, but at least the first cycle should behave exactly as `next()` did, because I am literally returning the value of `next()`.

My html looks like:

```
<div id="parent>
  <div class="common_class"></div>
  <div class="common_class"></div>
  <div class="common_class"></div>
  <div class="common_class"></div>
  <div class="undesired_elemement"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with Firebug or Chrome's developer tools? You will be able to see the code path that is executed that way, and inspect variables to see what "this" is any given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return in the `each` **callback** has no effect. Your rotator function returns whatever **`each`** returns, and that is not what the callback returns, but it returns `this` again.

Solution: Don't use `each`:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend.rotater = function(class_check){
        if(this.next().hasClass(class_check)){
            return this.next();
        else {
            return this.parent().children().first();
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You only have to use `this.each` if you want to apply a functionality to all elements the selector selected.

You might experience weird behaviour though if more than one element is selected. In this case you should select the first element explicitly:

```
var ele = this.eq(0);
```